# Convert string to array after count five comma in the string using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, substring

I have a string is below,

```
$string = "div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading: Quick Link|  isactive:1,0,0, div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading:Image|  isactive:1,4,0, div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:Social|  isactive:1,8,0";"
```

Now I would like to convert this string as a sub-string to be an array element is as below,

```
$array = [
    "div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading: Quick, Link| isactive:1,0,0",
    "div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading:Image| isactive:1,4,0",
    "div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:Social| isactive:1,8,0",
];
```

After five commas counted in the `$string`, a substring will be converted as an array element.
How can I do it using PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) method to solve this

```php
<?php

$string = "
div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading: Quick Link|  isactive:1,0,0,  
div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading:Image|  isactive:1,4,0,  
div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:Social|  isactive:1,8,0";


$temp = explode(',', $string); // just create one big array
$temp = array_chunk($temp, 5); // group the array per 5 parts
foreach($temp as &$value) $value = trim(implode(',', $value)); // recombine to one string

var_dump($temp);
```

[demo](http://www.ideone.com/HnQdlL)

Comment: This and the preg_match_all are probably the most robust solutions

Answer (score 3):

Based on the input string in the question, you can also use [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), splitting on a comma followed by a newline:

```
$array = preg_split('/,\s+/', trim($string));
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading: Quick Link|  isactive:1,0,0
    [1] => div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading:Image|  isactive:1,4,0
    [2] => div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:Social|  isactive:1,8,0
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/iJ6Cd)

**Update**

Based on the comments, I now understand there isn't intended to be any whitespace in the string. In this case, you can still use `preg_split` with a more complex regex, and using the flags `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` to capture the contents of the regex and `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to remove empty strings from the result:

```
$array = preg_split('/((?:[^,]+,){4}[^,]+),\s*/', trim($string), -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($array);
```

Output is the same. [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kqFbJ)

Comment: No Nick. It's a one-line string. No whitespace. Context is clearly after 5th comma.

Comment: @Rahul in the question the string has whitespace. That's what I'm answering (as did one of the others).

Comment: @Nick I think the OP broke out the string to multiple lines to make it more readable, which inadvertently changed the question, but +1 to you anyway.

Comment: @Nick Tim is right! Pardon mate! To make it more readable I did editing :p.

Comment: @Rahul You should unedit the question as there are other answers that rely on the white space. I've updated my answer with a more robust whitespace independent solution.

Comment: @Nick +1 from me too. I did what you say, mate! \M/ here's [another regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721669/regex-expression-for-comma-or-space-separated-string) for you!

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `preg_match_all` here with the following regex:

```
((?:[^,]*,){4}[^,]+)(?:,|$)
```

This will match a term having fives commas, but won't capture the final fifth comma as the first capture group.

```
$string = "
    div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading: Quick Link| isactive:1,0,0,  
    div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading:Image|  isactive:1,4,0,  
    div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:Social|  isactive:1,8,0";

preg_match_all("/((?:[^,]*,){4}[^,]+)(?:,|$)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading: Quick Link| isactive:1,0,0
    [1] => div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading:Image|  isactive:1,4,0
    [2] => div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:Social|  isactive:1,8,0
)
```

Comment: This and the array_chunk are probably the most robust solutions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP expert, but its just a split and reform in any language.

```
<?php

$string = "div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading: Quick Link|  
isactive:1,0,0,div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading:Image|  
isactive:1,4,0,div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:Social|  
isactive:1,8,0";
$items = explode("div-item",$string);
$target = array();
foreach( $items as $item){
    if($item !== '')
        array_push($target,"div-item".$item);
}

print_r($target); //Your array

?>
```

Will yield

```
Array
(
    [0] => div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading: Quick Link|  
isactive:1,0,0,
    [1] => div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading:Image|  
isactive:1,4,0,
    [2] => div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:Social|  
isactive:1,8,0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any newlines in the shown string.
And is the number of commas always the same for the separation?
What is in the original: "heading: Quick, Link" or "heading: Quick Link"?
The expected array shows me that every array element should start with a "div". Why not use "div" or "div-item" to separate?
Under these conditions do also do that:

```
$string = "div-item-0,4,maintype:menu| heading: Quick Link|  isactive:1,0,0, div-item-1,4,maintype:text| heading:Image|  isactive:1,4,0, div-item-2,4,maintype:social| heading:Social|  isactive:1,8,0";

$array = preg_split('~(?=div)~', $string,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```