# Regex to validate the string with comma or space separated

Tags: php, regex, laravel, yii2

I am trying to get string through input box from user
user can add only numbers in the string the format of a string is like this
Example
123456,111111,122335
123456 111111 122335
only "," or " " are allowed after 6 digits of number like show in example

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i want a regular expression that accept only 6 number then comma or space then next 6 numbers and soo on

Comment: can you please more clarification on `not comma or space together`  does this mean in a string only one separator can be used or it means both of them can't be used at same time between two digits, i.e `123456,123456 123456` or `123456, 123456`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:(?:\d{6},)*|(?:\d{6}\s+)*)\d{6}$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/gegbYy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This regexp is for 3 groups of 6 digits:

```
\d{6}(?: |,)\d{6}(?: |,)\d{6}
```

You can [test it here](https://regex101.com/r/Utvj9l/1).